# Why do match() and split() produce different results?

Tags: regex, string, actionscript-3, split

Why do `match` and `split` produce different results?  This is in Actionscript 3.0, but if this is also true outside of AS3, I would like to know why for that as well.

Example:

```
var txt:String = "somethingorother";
var re:RegExp = /(\w{2,2})/g;
trace("\t txt.split = " + txt.split(re) + " -- " + txt.split(re).length);
trace("\t txt.match = " + txt.match(re) + " -- " + txt.match(re).length);
```

Results:

```
txt.split = ,so,,me,,th,,in,,go,,ro,,th,,er, -- 17
txt.match = so,me,th,in,go,ro,th,er -- 8
```

### Edit:

With the conditions given, I expect the results to be an identical array (with the exception, in this case, of `match` not finding a final entry for odd-length `Strings`).  Why is there the extra entries in the `split`?  What is `split` finding that `match` is getting "correct"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`split` splits a string by another string or by a regular expression, keeping any parenthesized groups if the argument is the latter case, which is the behavior you are seeing currently. It is not intended to have the same functionality as `match` at all, which is used to retrieve one or many matches of a regular expression on a string.

---

`split` will split a string by your regular expression, and keep the parenthesized groups - as separate entries. Therefore, when splitting, the matches are kept separate from the string between them, which is empty - hence your result.

Comment: With the conditions given, I expect the results to be an identical array (with the exception, in this case, of `match` not finding a final entry for odd-length `Strings`).  Why, in this case, is there the extra entries in the `split`?  What is `split` finding that `match` is getting "correct"?

Comment: @iND: `split` will split a string by your regular expression, and keep the parenthesized groups - as *separate entries*. Therefore, when splitting, the matches are kept separate from the string between them, which is empty - hence your result.

Comment: Follow-up:  Why is `split` finding any empty entries?  I don't understand why it is not finding two words in the first place . . . where is it getting the empty results from?  Shouldn't it be two identical sets of `\w{2,2}` chars in consecutive entries?

Comment: @iND: Think of `split` as finding all of the matches, and also finding everything between the matches, *even if what is between the matches is an empty string*.

Comment: If you take away the the parentheses, you get an array of empty strings.  Please test it to see if you get the same results.  The follow-up question is: why aren't there any non-empty results from **txt.split(/\w{2,2}/g)**?  Is there a mistake in the regular expression?  (Maybe I should make this a separate Stackoverflow question. . . .)

Comment: @iND: `split` will only keep the matches if they are in parenthesized groups. Otherwise, it discards them.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I understood the `split` docs, but I guess I have to rethink them.  :)